# How can I solve this issue with getting a firebase app to work with javascript and webpack?

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I am making an app where I'm uploading and updating information onto a database through firebase/firestore. Everything works fine when I tested the firestore project with a single document, but when I link to another document with the rest of the project code, I am getting a myriad of errors depending on the small adjustments I make, the most common being "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module", along with "ReferenceError: document is not defined". The former is referring to the fact that the files need to be of type module, but when I fix that I am then getting the latter error. And then I can't fix the latter error because node js does not work with the client side. Keep in mind I am checking this from the terminal by the command node index2.js. I have tried reconfiguring the files, but that does not seem to make a difference. I have tried making certain changes to the package.json file but that has not fixed anything. I have also read about configuring a webpack.config.js file, but I do not know how I would configure that.

Here is the code from the main file that's connecting to firebase. Take extra notice of what's going on on the top. The rest of the file is probably working. I'm trying to import a function that was exported from easy.js but that has not been working because of the errors I mentioned above. Below that is the current package.json.

I'm assuming the issue is something having to do with some combination of not having a certain tool as a dependency, not having one of the other files not configured properly (ie not having a webpack config file or some missing info on the firebase config file), or needing the files/folders to be organized differently. If there's another tool I can use that isn't webpack that might be better, or if there's another tool that I'm missing, please let me know as well.

```
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountWaldo.json');

 admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
 });
 const db = admin.firestore();

 import _ from 'lodash';

 import { picList } from './easy.js';


 const asyncFunction = async() => {

     const result = await getPicture();
     console.log(result);
     const obj = result;
     const quoteData = {
         pics: obj.pics,
     };

     const collection = db.collection('pictures').doc('pics');
 
     collection.set(quoteData)
        .then(() =>
            console.log('game pictures now on database'));
     }


    function getPicture(){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         resolve({
             picList
            
         });
       })
     }


    asyncFunction();
```

package.json

```
 {
   "name": "waldo",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index2.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "author's name",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
     "webpack": "^5.4.0",
     "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "firebase": "^8.0.0",
     "firebase-admin": "^9.3.0",
     "lodash": "^4.17.20"
   }

 }
```

Comment: So you're trying to use firebase-admin in a web app instead of the normal web SDKs as illustrated in the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers

Comment: That's what I've been doing so far yeah. What might you recommend that would make things easier? It seems like there are a million ways to set this up and I did this through an idea from a tutorial

Comment: Don't use firebase-admin in a web app.  It's designed to work on backends running nodejs.  Instead, use the instructions I linked to.

Comment: Ok- the instructions are vague and the app is already initiated and I don't really know what to do on firebase init command. Can you try to fill me in on what exactly I'm doing?

Comment: If you're having problems with those instructions, post what you've tried so far, starting from the top, and explain what isn't working the way you expect.  Most people don't have a problem following them.

Comment: I'm expecting the content on the firestore database to change, and ideally also being told what changed in the terminal. That's what the node command did. Firebase init command is giving me a list of options, and it's not clear which one would be that. Options are deploy reatime database rules, deploy rules and indexes, config/deploy functions, config/deploy hosting sites, deploy security rules, set up emulators, and remote config

Comment: Please post those details as a new question.  If you're done trying to use the admin sdk, I suggest deleting this questions.